# UpdateList objects on property changed

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I am trying to update a page when change one value from one of the items in a list.

I have the following ListView in my XAML

```xml
<ListView
   x:Name="ItemsListView"
   CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
   HasUnevenRows="true"
   IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
   IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
   ItemTapped="ItemsListView_ItemTapped"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
   RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <ViewCell>
               <StackLayout
                   Padding="10"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <Label
                       FontSize="16"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                       Text="{Binding displayProduct}" />

                   <Label
                       FontSize="16"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                       Text="{Binding quantity}" />

                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In the pages code, I have a function that search if one of the ListItems has the corresponding EAN as a property, and if yes increment it's quantity.

```cs
ListItemScanList itemSelected = new ListItemScanList();
foreach (ListItemScanList item in viewModel.Items)
{
    if (item.EAN == barcode)
    {
        found = true;
        itemSelected = item;
        break;
    }
}

if (found)
{
    itemSelected.quantity += 1;
    await Common.UpdateScanList(barcode, itemSelected.quantity);
}
```

And in the ViewModel, I have the list of items that I update with a call to `OnPropertyChanged()`, but the view doesn't update when I change the value. Am I doing something wrong?

```cs
public class ScanListViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string _mode = "MULTI";
    public ScanList _scanList;
    public int _total = 0;

    public ScanListViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Scanning";
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ListItemScanList>();
        LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());
    }

    ObservableCollection<ListItemScanList> _items;

    public ObservableCollection<ListItemScanList> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; OnPropertyChanged("Items"); }
    }
}
```

Edit: Adding the ListItems from the models

```cs
public class ListItemScanList
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public string productName { get; set; }
    public string stockID { get; set; }
    public string EAN { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }

    public string displayProduct
    {
        get { return stockID + " " + productName; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `ListItemScanList`. It seems like the properties of that class aren't raising `PropertyChanged` events. Your `ObservableCollection<ListItemScanList>` only propagates changes to the collection itself, but if you need to react to changes to individual items, then the model `ListItemScanList` must also raise notifications.

Comment: @ewerspej I think that is the issue. I've added the definition of ListItem. Thanks for the help with formatting as well ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to react to changes to a specific object, you need to make sure that the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is implemented for that specific class, so that the properties can raise the `PropertyChanged` event when their values change.

In your particular case, the `ListItemScanList` class should look like this (or similar, you could also inherit from `ObservableObject` or another base class that already implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface) using a backing field for the property and then making a call to `OnPropertyChanged()` when the value changes:

```cs
public class ListItemScanList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string productName { get; set; }
    public string stockID { get; set; }
    public string EAN { get; set; }

    private int _quantity;
    public int quantity
    {
        get => _quantity;
        set
        {
            if(_quantity == value) return;
            _quantity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string displayProduct
    {
        get { return stockID + " " + productName; }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

**Note:** It's a common practice that property names start with a capital letter. So your properties should be called `ProductName`, `StockId`, `Quantity` etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you change some property e.g. `quantity` you have to notify the View of this change with `PropertyChanged` event because properties in inner models notified about their changes independently.

So you need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your `ListItemScanList` class and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the `quantity` property's setter. This will notify the view that the `quantity`  has changed, and it needs to update the UI.

```
public class ListItemScanList : BaseViewModel
{
    private int _quantity;
    public int quantity
    {
        get { return _quantity; }
        set
        {
            _quantity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("quantity");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I indeed seem to have misunderstood some things, I did not do anything special to the ListItemScanList to make it work. I'll look in there.